# How to add an event listener to trigger a server side email function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, I have an express application serving a static index.html page, and a function in my app.js file that sends an email when the server starts up.

What I'd like to do is send the email only when a user hits a 'submit' button on a form (and the form is successfully sent, so on success-confirmation, preferably).

How do I get my program to "listen" for an onClick / form-successfully-sent event and then run the server side code I have that sends an email?

```
const http = require('http');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('index.html'))

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'USERNAME@GMAIL.COM',
    pass: 'PASSWORD'
  }
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: 'USERNAME@GMAIL.COM',
  to: 'USERNAME2@GMAIL.COM',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
})
```

I would like to trigger the transporter.sendMail method/function when a user successfully submits a form.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't listen for events from the client webpage on your server, you run code in response to requests. And then you make your frontend webpage make a request when you press the submit button.

Comment: Add an other route (like **app.post('/sendmail', function(req, res){})**, and call that on submit. Basically create a (simple) API.

Comment: @AlexWayne & muka.gergely, that makes a lot of sense. I completely forgot about this part of express. Still learning! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a route on your server that will handle form submissions.  There are multiple ways to do this, however, as a simple example, look at the code below:

```
app.post("/send", function(req, res, next) {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "test-email@gmail.com",
      pass: "test123"
    }
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${req.body.email}`,
    to: "test-email@gmail.com",
    subject: `${req.body.name}`,
    text: `${req.body.message}`,
    replyTo: `${req.body.email}`
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("there was an error: ", err);
    } else {
      console.log("here is the res: ", res);
    }
  });
});
```

Then, in your client application, call the function below (or something similar) to send the client-side data to the newly-created endpoint:

```
function sendEmail(name, email, message) {
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      message: message
    })
  };

  return fetch("/send", options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log("here is the response: ", res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error("here is the error: ", err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set up an API endpoint

```js
app.post('/send-mail', function (req, res) {
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  })
})
```

And then call that from your form code.

```js
onSubmit() {
  fetch('/send-mail', {
        method: 'POST'
  })
}
```

Edit: typo.

Answer (score 0):

Put this part inside a function and call it when you handle your form request, create parameters in function as needed for f.ex. mailOptions information

```
function sendEmail(){ 
    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'USERNAME@GMAIL.COM',
        to: 'USERNAME2@GMAIL.COM',
        subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
        text: 'That was easy!'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");   

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: `${req.body.username}`,
    pass: `${req.body.password}`
  }
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: `${req.body.email}`,
  to: 'USERNAME2@GMAIL.COM',
  subject: ``${req.body.subject},
  text: `${req.body.message}`
};

 app.post("/login", (req, res)=>{
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
  if (error) {
     console.log(error);
       } else {
          console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
           }
})
    })
```

remember to do `npm install --save body-parser` and also `app.use(bodyparser.json())`